# доступ к ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, область-видимости

Есть метод, где выполняется запрос:

```
public static ResultSet selectTemplates() throws SQLException {
    String select = "select * from templates";
    Connection connection = DBConnector.getDBConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(selectTemplates);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    return resultSet;
}
```

Есть другой метод, где происходит  обращение к resultSet и попытка забить значения в Map:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
...
ResultSet resultSet = database.SQL.selectTemplates();
while (resultSet.next()) {
      map.put(resultSets.getString("id"), false);
      }
...
}
```

В таком виде resultSet доступен и отдаёт данные. Но если я меняю первый метод, добавляя try:

```
public static ResultSet selectTemplates() throws SQLException {
String select = "select * from templates";
try (Connection connection = DBConnector.getDBConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(selectTemplates)) {
     ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
     return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Я получаю ошибку:
**Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Закрытый набор результатов: next**

Объясните, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выдержка из JavaDoc к ResultSet классу

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.

Ваш try с ресурсом закрывает Statement